# JavaScript: Making sure form values are unique, Java Spring Rest as backend

Tags: javascript, java, spring, rest

I've a very simple REST api that allows user creation. I've no prior experience with frontend therefore I don't know how to properly use JavaScript. Here is my form:

```
<form action="/user" method="get">
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="inser username..."><br>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="insert name..."><br><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="insert surname..."><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How to validate in realtime (asynchronous?) that Username (login) is taken or free? I know that I have to somehow receive information from database.  I would like to display message under username form field before sending the whole form.

Comment: You really want to make a call to the server and to database on every keyup ??

Comment: is it not common to do that? Many services like Facebook and Gmail seem to check unique values in real time.  Maybe there is other way round?

Comment: Depending on the volume of users your application will need more resources to not collapse...you could do a check againt database when the user start typing the password. Gmail for example have to steps..you put the email and the the password.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onKeyUp` attribute of a input element to recognize, if the user is instering something into the field.

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="inser username..." onkeyup="searchForName(this.value)">
```

You can use this event to start a function that runs an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request to your server which can execute a querxy against your database to check if the user exists or not. It works like a livesearch. Here is an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) for that. I suggest to use JQuery Ajax call an not the shown XMLHttpRequest. In my opinion it easier.

Edit: In your case you would supplement the PHP file with a Java file. You can use the url in the ajax request to start a query against your REST backend which supplies the neccessary information.

Comment: Thank you, just question out of curiosity, is it performance safe to do it this way, or better to send whole request and after that let user know if username is taken?

Comment: Indeed it is not an efficient usage of resources, because you check each substring of the username. Anyway I think you won't have any performance issues. If you want to improve the process you can just check the username if the has left the input field and inserted something. You can check if a focused field has been left with `<input type="text" onfocusout="checkName(this.value)">` and a function like this:
`function(name) {
   if(name.length>0) {
      runAjax();
   }
}`

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

You send the new user request with the data.

In the backend you test that the user dosn't exist first.

If dosn't exists you save it and your response is OK

If already exists your response is KO.

In the frontend when you get the response back check the error field and do whatever.

Make a custom response like this for example.

```
{ 
 error: false,
 resultMsg:"User OK"
}

{ 
 error: true,
 resultMsg:"User with name XXX already exists"
}
```

**Option 2**

Instead of check if user exists on login, you can checkit when user puts the password.

For this, use the onfocusout event

```
 <input id="userInput" type="text" onfocusout="myFunction()">
```

In the function do the necessary checks against the user input and whatever

```
function myFunction() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
    // check whatever, length, etc ...
    if(userInput.value) {
         // do ajax call to backend 
          ...
         //  on response, check if error

    }
}
```

And the do a request againts backend to check if user exists.

Then is same as in option 1

Comment: Thank you, so I understand that it's much better to first send whole request instead of checking single input value in real time?